# Rails 3: Strange devise redirect error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes, mongoid

So, I got an interesting problem. I am attempting to override and redirect a devise sign_up and sign_in request to their appropriate profile pages but I am running into an error. The profiles and URL work by accessing it with console, link_to or by typing it out. For some reason the devise method won't route to it. I'm not sure why. Anyways, upvotes for all that contribute or solve. Thanks!

**Routes:**

```
  root :to => 'pages#index'
  get "pages/index"

  devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts', :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

  get 'users/:id/profile' => 'profiles#show', :as => 'current_profile'
  get 'users/:id/profile/edit' => 'profiles#edit', :as => 'edit_current_profile'
  put 'users/:id/profile' => 'profiles#update'

  resources :users do
    resources :profiles 
  end
```

**Registration Controller:**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
     edit_current_profile_path(resource)
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     current_profile_path(resource)
  end

end
```

**Profile Controller**

```
  def show
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profile

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
    end
  end
```

**Error message:**

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"profiles", :action=>"show"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

**View: edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@profile.user, @profile]) do |f| %>
  <% if @profile.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@profile.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this profile from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @profile.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :real_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :real_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give an attribute to your route helpers. Try it out

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   edit_current_profile_path(resource)
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   current_profile_path(resource) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I got the attributes tacked on there now but still the same error

Comment: It may be caused by route helpers in your view. Can you add profile edit page to your question?

Comment: Okay. Just updated it. It's weird because I can update the profile for the different users if I manually go to the URLs.

Comment: Didn't find anything criminal here, sorry. Still thinking that error caused by invalid route helper. Something like `profile_path` instead of `user_profile_path`.

Comment: So I changed get to match and it stops giving me the error! Thanks for the feedback.